# When runing fabric-java-sdks something go wrong with the offical example, how to slove it?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.Contract;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.ContractException;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.Gateway;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.Network;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.Wallet;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.Wallets;

class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Load an existing wallet holding identities used to access the network.
        Path walletDirectory = Paths.get("wallet");
        Wallet wallet = Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletDirectory);

        // Path to a common connection profile describing the network.
        Path networkConfigFile = Paths.get("connection.json");

        // Configure the gateway connection used to access the network.
        Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder()
                .identity(wallet, "user1")
                .networkConfig(networkConfigFile);

        // Create a gateway connection
        try (Gateway gateway = builder.connect()) {

            // Obtain a smart contract deployed on the network.
            Network network = gateway.getNetwork("mychannel");
            Contract contract = network.getContract("fabcar");

            // Submit transactions that store state to the ledger.
            byte[] createCarResult = contract.createTransaction("createCar")
                    .submit("CAR10", "VW", "Polo", "Grey", "Mary");
            System.out.println(new String(createCarResult, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            // Evaluate transactions that query state from the ledger.
            byte[] queryAllCarsResult = contract.evaluateTransaction("queryAllCars");
            System.out.println(new String(queryAllCarsResult, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        } catch (ContractException | TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identity not found in wallet: user1
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.GatewayImpl$Builder.identity(GatewayImpl.java:114)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.GatewayImpl$Builder.identity(GatewayImpl.java:66)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:25)

How to slove it please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must first make use of the SDK to create a wallet for your identity. For this purpose, you can follow the scripts as described in the [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4) repository inside the `fabric-samples/fabcar/java` directory.

1. Follow the `EnrollAdmin.java` script to enroll the admin identity in the wallet.
2. Follow the `RegisterUser.java` to register a new user identity and add it to the wallet.
3. Try using your current script now to perform different chaincode related operations.